# Domain Masking to URL on LAMP VPS

Tags: lamp, mask, masking, cname

I have a LAMP server where my main site is hosted on a VPS.

The main site runs off Joomla.

I have a page setup for each client :

```
mainsite.com/index.php?option=com_ ....
```

The site has rewrite abilities to create SEF URLS like :

```
mainsite.com/client1.html
mainsite.com/client2.html
mainsite.com/client3.html
```

These pages are single pages with no relative links to other mainsite.com pages.  They are simply stand alone brochure pages.

Can I setup my server to allow the clients to point their domain to my server and display the page content while the browser address bar shows their domain, and not the mainsite URL?

client1.com  displays  mainsite.com/client1.html content but still shows client1.com in the address bar.

...so a "mask" not a "redirect".

Is this possible using CNAME records? or something?  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: BUMP - Anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually dependent on the registrar. A lot of domain registrars offer the ability to forward the domain with masking, but the method varies from registrar to registrar.

Another method that will work no matter what is to point the domain at hosting and place an index.html file in that hosting that creates the mask as so:

```
<frameset>
  <frame src="http://mainsite.com/client1.html">
</frameset>
```

Comment: RE: FRAME - Yeah, FRAME would be functional, but not optimal because of SEO right?  The client sites would have no content in the eyes of search engines, and that would be a deal breaker

Comment: RE: Mask at Domain Registrar - This is only available if you host the sites with the registrar too...I believe, which is no good...but means technically it can be done - since they can do it.